# Best place to declare functions in this example

Tags: javascript, coding-style, node.js

Suppose I have code that accepts html GET requests:

```
server.get('path/to/some/endpoint', function(req,res) {
    function a() {
        //function goes here
    }
}
```

Is it better to declare functions (like a()) outside the server.get's callback scope?  What are the pro's/con's to each?

Comment: I hope this is a appropriate question for programmers.stackexchange - let me know if I should move it somewhere else though.

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring a **local scope function** in this case. This means it will only be available withing your scope which is very limited.

If you are not planing to reuse it, I wouldn't declare a function all together. if you are planing to reuse it, I would move it outside the callback scope into  a separate module/class depending on what the responsibility of the function is.

**Ideally you want to keep your routing clean of any extra steps other than routing.** This is [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).